# 2D semiconductor's time reversal symmetry

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, symmetry-breaking, crystals, time-reversal-symmetry

We know that 2d semiconductors have time-reversal symmetry breaking' properties.

How can I check the spatial inversion symmetry properties and time-reversal symmetry of materials?

Please explain it easily.